# How to make sure My Backend APIs Are being called by my Client Applications only and not through other channels like Postman

Tags: android

how can I make sure My Backend APIs Are being called by my Client Applications only and not through other channels like Postman.

I do have user access token in my android app but some data is public which does not require any type of user access token or users can access without login. how can I add token based access to those services (when user is not signed in). How is this use case generally handled.

Comment: Waste of time. Why would you need that for?

Answer (score -1):

So this case can be handled in two ways. On is complex but has benefits in terms of security and user onboarding, the other one is simpler but doesn't have above features

1. You can create a temporary user for first time app openers, you can create a token for them, store it in pref, and restrict all the APIs to have such token. In this case you need to handle scenarios like there will be no profile details and much more based on the app. You can also merge that user with existing user when logged in.
2. Create a static header like "device_type: Android" and place that in your app too and restrict the APIs and they must receive the header.

Comment: either of these can easily be forger using Postman, curl or antyhing

Comment: For the first one to forger, user will need to call the getToken API first. But if you want even more security, You can add some unique headers in API and android app that are difficult to assume. It will add like a password

Comment: please do not put "if you want more security" and "add more headers" in one sentence :) And no, this changes nothing at all. Also no, it is not "difficult to assume". It is in fact pretty "public" as it flies over the network. MITM, proxy or rev-env of the client app and you good.